# ReactJS props.title not displaying

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, components, react-props

The posts I have on database (using MongoDB) doesn't append on my Projects Dashboard and I did debugging and doesn't show any error...May it's about how I showing it? props or something?!

My PageProjects:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import Projects from '../../components/pages/Projects/Projects/Projects';
import './PageProjects.css';


class PageProjects extends Component {

state = {
    posts:[],
} 


 componentDidMount(){
 fetch('/projects')
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(posts => this.setState({posts}));
 }

 render(){
    const projects = this.state.posts.map(post => {
        return <Projects
        key={post._id}
        title={post.title}
        typeOfProduction={post.typeOfProduction}
        />
    })
  return (
      <div>
          <section className="Posts">
          {projects}
          </section>                    
      </div>
  );

}
}
export default PageProjects;
```

and this is my projects/posts:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Projects.css';


const projects = (props) => (
<div className="Dashboard container-fluid">
<article className="Post" >
      <h1 >{props.title}</h1>
      <div className="Info">
         <div className="TypeOfProduction">{props.typeOfProduction}    </div>
      </div>
    </article>
</div>
 );

export default projects;
```

and it shows like this:
[image]

**my console.log(this.state.posts) ->**
[image]

Comment: Can you please do console log of this.state.posts and share the code

Comment: sorry can you please add this in question. Unable to understand from comment

Comment: @Think-Twice done! :)

Comment: added my answer. You need to add return in functional component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PageProjects component render do this

```
  const projects = this.state.posts && this.state.posts.map(post => {
    return <Projects
    key={post._id}
    title={post.title}
    typeOfProduction={post.typeOfProduction}
    />
   })
```

And in your functional component You need to add return

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import './Projects.css';


  const Projects = (props) => {
     return (<div className="Dashboard container-fluid">
           <article className="Post" >
                <h1 style={{color: "red"}}>{props.title}</h1>
                <div className="Info">
                <div className="TypeOfProduction">{props.typeOfProduction}    </div>
               </div>
          </article>
       </div>)}

 export default Projects;
```

Comment: Done, but nothing changed :( maybe its the "map" method that is wrong?

Comment: You are saying there is no error. My last attempt for you. In functional component your component name is in lowercase but you are importing as Projects. I updated my answer again take Projects component code and give a try

Comment: nothing.. but I'll try to see if I missed anything else..Thank you so much for your help!!! :D